# does hive support optional field in struct

Tags: hive

thrift does support optional fields in struct

```
struct Name {                                                                                                                                
  1: string firstname,
  2: optional string middlename,
  3: string lastname,
}
```

but does hive support to create a table with similar struct type, please?
I checked hive's tutorial and found no way to set 'optional' keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Hive supports NULL values. You can define a table with three fields:

- firstname
- middlename
- lastname

The middlename field would contain NULLs for the records corresponding to the cases when a person (I presume) doesn't have a middle name or the middle name is not known.